# I am new to node.js.while writing a code iam getting an syntax error unexpected identifier at config=

Tags: node.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
Twit = require('twit'),
config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));

var T = new Twit(config);

T.post('statuses/update', { status: 'My first tweet!' }, function(err, data, response) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: You used commas instead of semicolons,

Comment: try to use const instead of var.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path'),
Twit = require('twit'),
```

change upper statements to this

```
var fs = require('fs');
path = require('path');
Twit = require('twit');
```